# One operation for Update if value doesn't exists in an array using mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering if it is possible with just one operation (or just one command) to update a document inside mongodb if the value used in the update doesn't exists in an array.

example mongodb document:

```
{ 
    regs : {
        someid : 12345,
        dataArray : [ { id  : 1 }, { id : 43 }, { id : 11 }]
    }
}
```

Now I want only to update if the id inside dataArray is not in use already, something like:

```
 db.regs.update({ someid : 12345 }, { $push : { dataArray : { id : INT }}})
```

Using the above line it's possible to check if `{ id : INT }` is alreay in my array and update only if it isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a couple of ways. For example you can use query matching document of interest:

```
db.regs.update(
    {someid : 12345, 'dataArray.id': {$ne: INT}},
    {$push : { dataArray : {id : INT }}}
)
```

or perform update using `addToSet`:

```
db.regs.update(
    {someid : 12345},
    {$addToSet : {dataArray : {id : INT }}}
)
```

Answer (score 3):

As @zero323 has already pointed out, there is an specific update operation with that specific use case in mind. From the [MongoDB documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/):

> `$addToSet`
>
> The `$addToSet` operator adds a value to an array only if the value is
>   not in the array already. If the value is in the array, `$addToSet`
>   returns without modifying the array.
>
> Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> db.collection.update( { field: value }, { $addToSet: { field: value1 } } );
> ```
>
> Here, `$addToSet` appends `value1` to the array stored in `field`,
>   only if `value1` is not already a member of this array.

Comment: Thank you for complementing the answer